# how to do Good SDK 3.1.0 integration with Xcode 8.3.2?

Tags: ios, xcode8

I have installed xcode v8.3.2 and trying to integrate good sdk v3.1.0, but I am unable to do so. When I went through release notes I found that this latest version will not support to Xcode 8.3 and later versions. But one of my colleagues is able to use the latest version of good sdk with Xcode 8.3.1 without any issue. How can we resolve this?

Comment: May be ask your colleagues ??

Comment: Of course,I asked him and he said he didn't find any issue when integrating this SDK?

Comment: And which issues are you facing ? please mention that

Comment: I am unable to find the good template in the template list soI am unable to create the sample project using the good template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you need to install Xcode and good sdk in the applications folder on the system.This is the way it worked for me.